# application development for iPhone Appstore

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

what does the domainname and application name in the APP ID generally means.
Can the iPhone unlocked one can be used for the iPhone Appstore application development and testing .
Can the iPhone jailBroken one can be used for the iPhone Appstore application development and testing .

As the process to test the application includes submission of the digital certificates from the apple and including the device UDID , i would like to know does apple makes the iPhone, not to allow the application running  or disable the appstore application or any sort of problems can be faced from apple or not..

Thank u

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully sure about what you mean, but from what I understand is that you have conserns if apple can deny an application to be installed in an iPhone that is Jailbroken?
If that is your question, no apple cannot. Apple cannot know which iPhones are jailbroken or not, not while developing and compiling it to your development device, nor when the application is released to the Appstore and customers buy/download your application.

You can find more information about [jailbreaking on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jailbreak_%28iPhone_OS%29).

I hope I was able to answer your question.